# DropShadowEffect causing quality to be lost

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm trying to create a style for my progress bar, but I can't seem to make it the same style as the image I intend to make.

**My progress bar at WPF:**

[image: image1]

**Style I want to create:**

[image: image2]

**Code Style:**

```
<Style x:Key="ProgBar" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Name="PART_Indicator" 
                        CornerRadius="2"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect Color="#FFF5E544" Direction="360" ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="15" RenderingBias="Quality"/>
                        </Border.Effect>
                    </Boder>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Code Xaml:**

```
<ProgressBar Style="{StaticResource ProgBar}" Width="100" Height="5" Value="90" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Transparent">
    <ProgressBar.Foreground>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" SpreadMethod="Pad">
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FFFFFF0B"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.445" Color="#FFFFc000"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#E67D1C"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </ProgressBar.Foreground>
</ProgressBar>
```

The gradient also doesn't look much the same, the gradient of wpf is very different from other tools.

Can someone help me to make the progress bar equal to the image?

Answer (score 0):

Try `UseLayoutRounding="True"` on border, like:

```
    <Border Name="PART_Indicator" 
    CornerRadius="2"
    Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    UseLayoutRounding="True">
```

it helped in my case.